# SVG <animation> tag loop

Tags: svg

```html
<svg width="1440px" height="701px" viewBox="0 0 1440 701" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg1125" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:anigen="http://www.anigen.org/namespace" anigen:version="0.8.1">
<defs id="defs5660"></defs><sodipodi:namedview id="base" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1" inkscape:cx="810.8967158125306" inkscape:cy="-295.2172080489532" inkscape:zoom="1"></sodipodi:namedview><g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1.8967158125306014 -1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="-1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="1.2828829057524445" style="" id="g5084">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_158_211)" id="path1109" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint1_radial_158_211)" id="path1546" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint2_radial_158_211)" id="path1105" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint3_radial_158_211)" id="path9613" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint4_radial_158_211)" id="path5676" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
            <defs id="defs7166" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445">
        <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(793.234 364.427) rotate(93.7767) scale(674.597 1329.92)">
            <stop offset="0.739912" stop-color="#FD9BE8" id="stop8843"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FD9BE8" stop-opacity="0" id="stop216"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint1_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(397.44 381.916) rotate(37.4589) scale(569.103 589.657)">
            <stop offset="0.298581" stop-color="#762DEE" id="stop119"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#762DEE" stop-opacity="0" id="stop6761"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint2_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(-5.75587e-05 -75.2444) rotate(48.8153) scale(908.471 1208.1)">
            <stop offset="0.310885" stop-color="#75CDFF" id="stop1294"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.505769" stop-color="#75CDFF" stop-opacity="0" id="stop1984"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint3_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(592.457 423.402) rotate(-49.4143) scale(283.314 381.136)">
            <stop stop-color="#FFDC62" id="stop766"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFDC62" stop-opacity="0" id="stop9632"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint4_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(-344.777 364.427) rotate(49.9565) scale(800.642 1088.26)">
            <stop offset="0.227079" stop-color="#AEDCD1" id="stop8253"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.547505" stop-color="#AEDCD1" stop-opacity="0" id="stop2864"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
</g>
<g id="g9528">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_158_210)" id="path772"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint1_radial_158_210)" id="path6917"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint2_radial_158_210)" id="path8119"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint3_radial_158_210)" id="path6745"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint4_radial_158_210)" id="path5864"></path>
            <defs id="defs9606">
        <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1016.23 291.623) rotate(115.365) scale(689.582 1174.79)">
            <stop offset="0.259999" stop-color="#FD9BE8" id="stop865"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FD9BE8" stop-opacity="0" id="stop8242"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint1_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(51.0171 425.842) rotate(42.541) scale(762.78 889.788)">
            <stop offset="0.298581" stop-color="#762DEE" id="stop8037"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#762DEE" stop-opacity="0" id="stop2620"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint2_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(670.629 274.947) rotate(102.25) scale(341.286 652.07)">
            <stop offset="0.616877" stop-color="#75CDFF" id="stop9223"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#75CDFF" stop-opacity="0" id="stop2355"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint3_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(921.6 517.356) rotate(-114.504) scale(484.085 833.011)">
            <stop stop-color="#FFDC62" id="stop489"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFDC62" stop-opacity="0" id="stop9266"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint4_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(817.92 364.427) rotate(125.929) scale(518.863 759.244)">
            <stop offset="0.227079" stop-color="#81F9F2" id="stop7546"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.547505" stop-color="#81F9F2" stop-opacity="0" id="stop6522"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
<animate attributeType="auto"  attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0 0 1 1" dur="3s"  begin="3s; anim2.end" repeatCount="1" additive="replace" accumulate="none" fill="freeze" id="animate6529"></animate><animate attributeType="auto" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0 0 1 1" dur="3s" begin="anim2.end;" repeatCount="1" additive="replace" accumulate="none" fill="freeze" id="animate8920"></animate></g>
<g id="g2956" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; opacity: 1;">
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="#D9D9D9" id="path7235"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_158_209)" id="path867"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint1_radial_158_209)" id="path9195"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint2_radial_158_209)" id="path6004"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint3_radial_158_209)" id="path8966"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint4_radial_158_209)" id="path9014"></path>
           <defs id="defs3105">
        <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(720 350.75) rotate(89.9112) scale(530.632 1089.25)">
            <stop stop-color="#FD9BE8" id="stop453"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FD9BE8" stop-opacity="0" id="stop5778"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint1_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(548.023 434.224) rotate(84.0732) scale(565.792 1151.85)">
            <stop offset="0.662802" stop-color="#762DEE" id="stop8232"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#762DEE" stop-opacity="0" id="stop7994"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint2_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(720 350.75) rotate(89.9278) scale(652.905 1340.25)">
            <stop stop-color="#75CDFF" id="stop9818"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.460519" stop-color="#75CDFF" stop-opacity="0" id="stop2013"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint3_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1268.85 681.905) rotate(-148.544) scale(335.688 301.395)">
            <stop stop-color="#FFDC62" id="stop2242"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFDC62" stop-opacity="0" id="stop6840"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint4_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1179.15 138.732) rotate(137.163) scale(907.817 1088.77)">
            <stop offset="0.227079" stop-color="#81F9F2" id="stop8880"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.810258" stop-color="#81F9F2" stop-opacity="0" id="stop3671"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
<animate attributeType="auto" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0 0 1 1" dur="3s" begin="0s" repeatCount="1" additive="replace" accumulate="none" fill="freeze" id="animate3982"></animate><animate attributeType="auto" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0 0 1 1" dur="3s" begin="6s" repeatCount="1" additive="replace" accumulate="none" fill="freeze" id="animate4897"></animate></g>
</svg>
```

I have this svg(background) and I have problem with animation. I need to loop it like start first animation on the end of last animation. I tried a lot of methods, like throw off animation time throw JS, tried begin="0s; anim.end" and all these methods didn't help me, maybe because I'm did something wrong. Also I used repeatCount="indefinite" and its not what I need, because it will repeat the animation but not repeat animation timing. I used anigen to animate this. Can someone fix this or explain how to make this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. I've keyed each animation to start when the next one finishes.

Note, you have to use the actual id of an animation when you're referencing it.

```html
<svg width="1440px" height="701px" viewBox="0 0 1440 701" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg1125" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:anigen="http://www.anigen.org/namespace" anigen:version="0.8.1">
<defs id="defs5660"></defs><sodipodi:namedview id="base" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1" inkscape:cx="810.8967158125306" inkscape:cy="-295.2172080489532" inkscape:zoom="1"></sodipodi:namedview><g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1.8967158125306014 -1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="-1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="1.2828829057524445" style="" id="g5084">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_158_211)" id="path1109" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint1_radial_158_211)" id="path1546" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint2_radial_158_211)" id="path1105" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint3_radial_158_211)" id="path9613" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint4_radial_158_211)" id="path5676" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445"></path>
            <defs id="defs7166" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -1.8967158125306014 1.2827919510468178)" anigen:transform-center-x="1.8956030763802119" anigen:transform-center-y="-1.2828829057524445">
        <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(793.234 364.427) rotate(93.7767) scale(674.597 1329.92)">
            <stop offset="0.739912" stop-color="#FD9BE8" id="stop8843"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FD9BE8" stop-opacity="0" id="stop216"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint1_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(397.44 381.916) rotate(37.4589) scale(569.103 589.657)">
            <stop offset="0.298581" stop-color="#762DEE" id="stop119"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#762DEE" stop-opacity="0" id="stop6761"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint2_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(-5.75587e-05 -75.2444) rotate(48.8153) scale(908.471 1208.1)">
            <stop offset="0.310885" stop-color="#75CDFF" id="stop1294"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.505769" stop-color="#75CDFF" stop-opacity="0" id="stop1984"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint3_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(592.457 423.402) rotate(-49.4143) scale(283.314 381.136)">
            <stop stop-color="#FFDC62" id="stop766"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFDC62" stop-opacity="0" id="stop9632"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint4_radial_158_211" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(-344.777 364.427) rotate(49.9565) scale(800.642 1088.26)">
            <stop offset="0.227079" stop-color="#AEDCD1" id="stop8253"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.547505" stop-color="#AEDCD1" stop-opacity="0" id="stop2864"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
</g>
<g id="g9528">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_158_210)" id="path772"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint1_radial_158_210)" id="path6917"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint2_radial_158_210)" id="path8119"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint3_radial_158_210)" id="path6745"></path>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 344.5 L 1290 372 L 1203.5 581.5 L 986 603.5 L 851 439.5 L 0 581.5 L 0 0 Z" fill="url(#paint4_radial_158_210)" id="path5864"></path>
            <defs id="defs9606">
        <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1016.23 291.623) rotate(115.365) scale(689.582 1174.79)">
            <stop offset="0.259999" stop-color="#FD9BE8" id="stop865"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FD9BE8" stop-opacity="0" id="stop8242"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint1_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(51.0171 425.842) rotate(42.541) scale(762.78 889.788)">
            <stop offset="0.298581" stop-color="#762DEE" id="stop8037"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#762DEE" stop-opacity="0" id="stop2620"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint2_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(670.629 274.947) rotate(102.25) scale(341.286 652.07)">
            <stop offset="0.616877" stop-color="#75CDFF" id="stop9223"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#75CDFF" stop-opacity="0" id="stop2355"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint3_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(921.6 517.356) rotate(-114.504) scale(484.085 833.011)">
            <stop stop-color="#FFDC62" id="stop489"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFDC62" stop-opacity="0" id="stop9266"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint4_radial_158_210" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(817.92 364.427) rotate(125.929) scale(518.863 759.244)">
            <stop offset="0.227079" stop-color="#81F9F2" id="stop7546"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.547505" stop-color="#81F9F2" stop-opacity="0" id="stop6522"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
<animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0 0 1 1" dur="3s"  begin="3s; animate8920.end" repeatCount="1" additive="replace" accumulate="none" fill="freeze" id="animate6529"/><animate attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0 0 1 1" dur="3s" begin="animate6529.end;" repeatCount="1" additive="replace" accumulate="none" fill="freeze" id="animate8920"/></g>
<g id="g2956" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; opacity: 1;">
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="#D9D9D9" id="path7235"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_158_209)" id="path867"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint1_radial_158_209)" id="path9195"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint2_radial_158_209)" id="path6004"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint3_radial_158_209)" id="path8966"></path>
    <path d="M0 0H1440V344.5L1290 372L1203.5 581.5L986 603.5L851 439.5L0 581.5V0Z" fill="url(#paint4_radial_158_209)" id="path9014"></path>
           <defs id="defs3105">
        <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(720 350.75) rotate(89.9112) scale(530.632 1089.25)">
            <stop stop-color="#FD9BE8" id="stop453"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FD9BE8" stop-opacity="0" id="stop5778"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint1_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(548.023 434.224) rotate(84.0732) scale(565.792 1151.85)">
            <stop offset="0.662802" stop-color="#762DEE" id="stop8232"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#762DEE" stop-opacity="0" id="stop7994"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint2_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(720 350.75) rotate(89.9278) scale(652.905 1340.25)">
            <stop stop-color="#75CDFF" id="stop9818"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.460519" stop-color="#75CDFF" stop-opacity="0" id="stop2013"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint3_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1268.85 681.905) rotate(-148.544) scale(335.688 301.395)">
            <stop stop-color="#FFDC62" id="stop2242"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFDC62" stop-opacity="0" id="stop6840"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="paint4_radial_158_209" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(1179.15 138.732) rotate(137.163) scale(907.817 1088.77)">
            <stop offset="0.227079" stop-color="#81F9F2" id="stop8880"></stop>
            <stop offset="0.810258" stop-color="#81F9F2" stop-opacity="0" id="stop3671"></stop>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
<animate attributeType="auto" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0 0 1 1" dur="3s" begin="0s;animate4897.end" repeatCount="1" additive="replace" accumulate="none" fill="freeze" id="animate3982"/><animate attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0 0 1 1" dur="3s" begin="animate3982.end+3s" repeatCount="1" additive="replace" accumulate="none" fill="freeze" id="animate4897"></animate></g>
</svg>
```